# maven tomcat7 redeploy lost file compared with the war file

Tags: maven-2, tomcat7

I am using [maven](/questions/tagged/maven) and [tomcat7](/questions/tagged/tomcat7) to develop web project,but I found a weird problem:**the redeployed project lost some files compared with the war file,thus I can not run the project after it redeployed**.

Let me say it step by step:

- This is the project structure of my [maven](/questions/tagged/maven) project:

[image]

- This is my configuration code of the **pom.xml** file:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.lucumt</groupId>
<artifactId>vm</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>vm</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
        <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
        <artifactId>velocity-tools</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>vm</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://localhost:8085/manager/text</url>
                    <server>tm7</server>
                    <path>/vm</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

- when I run **tomcat7:deploy** in [eclipse](/questions/tagged/eclipse) using **m2eclipse** when **tomcat7** is running,the project is packaged as *vm.war* and it will deployed in  **webapps** folder for **tomcat7**,the file in **vm** folder will look like this,and I can run my project now:

[image]

- But when I run **tomcat7:redeploy**,the file in the **vm** folder will look like below,the [jsp](/questions/tagged/jsp) and [velocity](/questions/tagged/velocity) file is missing and thus I can not run this project using [tomcat](/questions/tagged/tomcat) again!

[image]

However,when I checked the **vm.war** file using **WinRA**,I found everything is okay,the [jsp](/questions/tagged/jsp) and [velocity](/questions/tagged/velocity) files are inside as below:

[image]

I think the files are missing  when [tomcat](/questions/tagged/tomcat) make the **vm.war** file in to **vm**,but I do not know why it happend,and I do not know how to solve it,can anyone help me? Is there is wrong configuration in my **pom.xml** file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried running `mvn clean package tomcat7:redeploy`? since deploy goal is identical to redeploy goal except that redeploy will undeploy a previous version, I think the problem you have is related to not having full package available.

Comment: @eis I just tried with **mvn clean package tomcat7:redeploy**,but the prolems still exists.

Comment: can you include the logs of what's happening with redeploy + deploy to this question? Preferrably run with `mvn -X` that shows also debug output.

Comment: also, you could try having `<update>true</update>` in your configuration section and see if deploy then works. It should be identical to redeploy, but doesn't hurt to test.

Comment: @eis,as you know,the deploy logs maybe a bit long,where can I put the logs for you?Thanks

Comment: they should preferrably be pasted into the question. It doesn't matter that much that they're long, since if you put them in code tags (like you should!), there will be a scrollbar so it wouldn't obstruct the view. Like what you have currently with pom.xml (so you probably already know this).

Comment: @eis,I have put my log file into http://paste.ubuntu.org.cn/2154510,you can find the log information from there!